# files with 2 exact underscores after file_root in current directoy

Tags: linux, bash, find

I Expect to find files with 2 underscores after file_root like this:

```
file_root_stringA_stringB.txt
```

where both stringA and stringB are in alnum class

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "file_root_*_*.txt"
```

but I stuck with:

```
file_root_aaa_bbb.txt # expected
file_root_aaa_bbb_c12.txt # not expecting
```

How can I get this in bash? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 2 -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex "^.*file_root_[^_]*_[^_]*\.txt"
```

Comment: This is the best so far, I would accept this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "file_root_*_*.txt" -not -name "file_root_*_*_*.txt"
```